# How to change/update a gem path route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, rubygems

When I run `rake db:migrate`, I get an error message that has this line in it:

```
/Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@global/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>
```

but when query the path route I get a different route:

```
Unkle-Andy:workspace andy$ gem which rake
/Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake.rb
```

Looking for a way to change/update the path route so that when I run the rake gem it looks for it in `/lib` instead of `/exe`. Or is this normal?

Just installed Ruby on Rails on my computer. I am running Ruby 2.5.0, Rails 5.1.4, and rake 12.3.0 on an Apple computer. I just uninstalled and reinstalled the Rake gem and am still getting the same mistake

Comment: Add complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

The `lib` part of path that `gem which rake` shows is normal; it's what before it most likely causes problems - this path and path shown in error message point to two different directories, containing different RVM gemsets. Try resetting your current gemset:

`rvm gemset use default` or `rvm gemset use global`

Comment: With the 'use default' i'm still getting the same problem: I know it's supposed to be in /lib, but why is it looking for it in /exe

With the 'use global' i can't even find the gem with 'gem which rake' anymore...

Comment: gem which rake doesn't show the rake executable file that you run - it is in exe, file in lib contains main module of rake gem that executable needs to load. If default gemset doesn't work, I would try to use global and run bundle again.

Comment: even with a sudo bundle, both in default and global i still get the error... should i just uninstall and reinstall ruby, rails, etc?

Comment: when using global, installing the rake gem returns: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@global/wrappers/byebug